# Twig syntax error when enabling ESI in symfony 2.1.8

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1, esi

Ive attempted to add an ESI render with {'standalone': true} to one of my twig templates and am getting the TWIG syntax error of:

`Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "," ("end of statement block" expected) in AccommMiddleBundle:Home:layout.html.twig at line 155`

here is the relevant twig template block:

```
150 <div class="container">
151     <h1>{{ blog_articles.0.title }}</h1>
152     <a href="{{blog_articles.0.guid}}">Moose</a>
153 </div>
154 
155 {% render url('accomm_middle_home_recent_articles', {fred: 1}), {'standalone': true} %}
156 
157 {% set charity_url = "http://www.accommodation.com/charity" %}
```

Removing the , {'standalone': true} gets the template to render fine.

Im using Symfony 2.1.8 with a clean vendors and there seems to be no differences with the standard edition dependencies. Any ideas on how to debug this ?

thanks for any help

MikeB

p.s. here are my installed packages

```
AccomDotCom/AccomDotComRESTClientBundle 0.1               The RESTFul models for talking to the Accommodation.com privateapi (baghdadsquirrel) via symfony
behat/behat                             v2.4.5            Scenario-oriented BDD framework for PHP 5.3
behat/gherkin                           v2.2.9            Gherkin DSL parser for PHP 5.3
behat/mink                              v1.4.3            Web acceptance testing framework for PHP 5.3
behat/mink-browserkit-driver            v1.0.4            Symfony2 BrowserKit driver for Mink framework
behat/mink-extension                    v1.0.1            Mink extension for Behat
behat/mink-selenium2-driver             v1.0.5            Selenium2 (WebDriver) driver for Mink framework
behat/mink-zombie-driver                v1.0.3            Zombie.js driver for Mink framework
behat/symfony2-extension                v1.0.1            Symfony2 framework extension for Behat
doctrine/common                         2.3.0             Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                           2.3.2             Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle                v1.0.0            Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/orm                            2.3.2             Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
guzzle/guzzle                           v2.8.7            Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client library and framework for building RESTful web service clients
instaclick/php-webdriver                1.0.12            PHP WebDriver for Selenium 2
jms/aop-bundle                          1.0.0             Adds AOP capabilities to Symfony2
jms/cg                                  1.0.0             Toolset for generating PHP code
jms/di-extra-bundle                     1.1.1             Allows to configure dependency injection using annotations
jms/metadata                            1.1.1             Class/method/property metadata management in PHP
jms/security-extra-bundle               1.2.0             Enhances the Symfony2 Security Component by adding several new features
kriswallsmith/assetic                   v1.1.0-alpha4     Asset Management for PHP
monolog/monolog                         1.2.1             Logging for PHP 5.3
nelmio/esi-debug-bundle                 1.0.0             Shows you caching information around ESI requests for debugging purposes
sensio/distribution-bundle              v2.1.8            The base bundle for the Symfony Distributions
sensio/framework-extra-bundle           v2.1.8            This bundle provides a way to configure your controllers with annotations
sensio/generator-bundle                 v2.1.8            This bundle generates code for you
swiftmailer/swiftmailer                 v4.2.2            Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/assetic-bundle                  v2.1.2            Integrates Assetic into Symfony2
symfony/monolog-bundle                  v2.1.8            Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle              v2.1.8            Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony                         v2.1.8            The Symfony PHP framework
twig/extensions                         dev-master v1.0.0 Common additional features for Twig that do not directly belong in core
twig/twig                               v1.12.2           Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP
vipsoft/jira-extension                  v1.0.9            Load features for Behat from Jira issues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Symfony2.1**, to adapt your render block to the correct notation, you need to

- put your arguments between single quote `'` : in this case you would have`'fred': 1`
- Add the `with{}` statement *even if it's empty*:

Which gives you:

```
{% render url('accomm_middle_home_recent_articles', {'fred': 1})  with {}, {'standalone': true} %}
```

---

Note: It looks like the `with{}` statement is absolutely needed in Symfony2.1, from this [security release](http://symfony.com/blog/security-release-symfony-2-0-20-and-2-1-5-released#cve-2012-6432-code-execution-vulnerability-via-the-internal-routes). However, Symfony might have changed this recently and I don't think it is needed in Symfony2.2 anymore.

> {# the with argument is needed but ignored #}

And an example they provide with it:

```
{% render url("path_to_controller_router", { 'param': 1 }) with {}, { 'standalone': true } %}
```

Comment: thanks @Patt was using the doco from [symfony http cache](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/http_cache.html#edge-side-includes) and didn't see the with {} buried in the security advisory. Now back to banging my head against the brick wall that is my varnish config :)

Comment: Great! If you are new to this site, don't forget to accept the answers if they solved your issue! Good luck with Varnish.

Comment: Well have been using this site for years but its my first question :).. have done thanks for the tip.